# Studying Freud and “The Uncanny”

Tags: freud

I meant to ask, do I need to study any of Freud’s other works before reading “The Uncanny”?
And, reading Freud (his whole body of work) have any prerequisites?

Comment: Welcome to psych.SE.  This question is soliciting opinion, which is against the rules here.  Please rephrase to something that can be answered authoritatively.  Also, check out: [Is Freudian Psychology a scientifically valid contribution to the Cognitive Sciences?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/18092/7001).